# Problem with Hangman game letters changing order, or solution changing to just one letter

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a hangman game and everything looks fine until I reach the end where sometimes the game says that the solution is just one character, or if I guess a letter they start changing places to the right. I leave you here with the code and I hope that someone can help me to find my error, thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define VOCABULARY_SIZE 8
#define MAX_STRING 32
#define MAX_GUESS 6

int random_number(int a, int b)
{
    return a + rand() % (b - a + 1);
}

int main()
{
    //random word selsection
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    const char VOCABULARY[VOCABULARY_SIZE][MAX_STRING] = {"vehicle", "building", "shirt", "pencil", "batman", "dromedary", "peach", "hangman"};
    char word[MAX_STRING];
    int i;
    i = random_number(0, VOCABULARY_SIZE - 1);
    strcpy(word, VOCABULARY[i]);

    //user word
    int guesses = 0, length = strlen(word);
    char letters[MAX_GUESS];
    char input[MAX_STRING];
    char temp_char;
    char temp_input[MAX_STRING];
    do
    {
        printf("\nYour entered letters are: ");
        printf("%s", letters);
        printf("\nYour letters found are: ");
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (word[j] == input[j])
            {
                printf("%c", word[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("_");
            }
        }
        printf("\n%d-letter word. %d out of %d failures. Enter a letter: ", length, guesses, MAX_GUESS);
        scanf(" %c", &temp_char);
        letters[guesses] = temp_char;
        letters[guesses+1] = '\0';
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (word[j] == temp_char)
            {
                input[j] = word[j];
            }
        }
        guesses++;
        printf("\nWhat is the word to guess? ");
        scanf(" %s", temp_input);
    } while ((strcmp(input, word) != 0 || strcmp(temp_input, word) != 0) && guesses <= MAX_GUESS);

    if (strcmp(input, word) == 0 || strcmp(temp_input, word) == 0)
    {
        printf("\nCongratulations, the word was %s!", word);
    }
    else if (guesses > MAX_GUESS)
    {
        printf("\nBetter luck next time... The word was %s", word);
    }
}
```

Comment: something is missing here`while ((strcmp(input, word) != 0 || (temp _input, word)!= 0) && guesses <= MAX_GUESS);`  for `(temp _input, word)`

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/64607282/2410359.

Answer (score 1):

Your `letters` array is one entry too small to hold the terminating nul character that you apply in this line:

```
    letters[guesses+1] = '\0';
```

You also have an off-by-one error since `guesses` starts at zero and your loop tests if it's `<= MAX_GUESS`.

These two errors in combination mean that your `letters` array is two bytes too small. Likely it spills over into your `word` array, leaving the last guess and the terminating nul in there when you go to print it.

Comment: Thank you! the array size solved a lot of problems, the guesses it is made like that so it goes from 0 to 6 and works like I want but thank you anyways, the only problem I have is that when you fail it foesnt print correctly the word idk why

Comment: @Ivan.2j It's because you write two bytes past the end of the `letters` array, likely corrupting the memory where the word is stored.

Comment: One fix would be to change `char letters[MAX_GUESS];` to ``char letters[MAX_GUESS]+2];`. One is for the terminating nul is one is because of MAX_GUESS is 6, you allow *7* guesses.